# Looking for regex to allow spaces but doesn't allow special characters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm implementing validation for registration form. One of the field is name, can have spaces but I don't want users to put any special characters.

Comment: Do you want users to be able to spell their names?

Comment: please define which characters are special ones first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(name, "^[a-z0-9 ]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```